# How to create a string out of a pandas Series of lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm encountering a Pandas issue when trying to convert an object (what pandas thinks is a list) to strings. The data I need to convert to strings are in a single Series column and look like this:

````
```
Col_A Col_B Series_Col
0     name  ['words.', 'more words', '26'] 
1     name  ['67,,,,...', 'words', 'words']
2     name  ['sup']
```
````

I've tried various solutions from here and none seem to work -- including writing the column to csv with the appropriate indexing and forcing it back in. Any guidance is appreciated.

The output I want is simple enough:

````
 Col_A Col_B Series_Col
 0     name  words. more words 26 
 1     name  67,,,,... words words
 2     name  sup
 ```
````

Comment: please provide us with some code so we can debug your problem. Have you tried `pd.DataFrame.to_string` ? Is your problem that your Series_Col is a list? Why don't you just use `" ".join(list)` on it?

Comment: *what pandas thinks is a list* -> is is **not** a list? Please provide your data as DataFrame constructor or dict

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col_A': [0,1,2],
    'Col_B': ['name','name','name'],
    'Series_Col': [['words.', 'more words', '26'], ['67,,,,...', 'words', 'words'],  ['sup']]
})

df['Series_Col'] = df['Series_Col'].apply(lambda x: " ".join(i for i in x))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Col_A  Col_B             Series_Col
0      0   name   words. more words 26
1      1   name  67,,,,... words words
2      2   name                    sup
```

Comment: Right, that was staring me in the face. Thanks for that!